# Image uploaded correctly but not updated in the view until refresh

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm working on an AngularJS app, and I'm fighting with the upload of the avatars.
The upload works just fine, but once it's done, the view isn't updated if the new file has the same extension than the old one (it works if the extensions are different, i.e. I'm uploading a `.jpeg` after a `.jpeg`). Here's a snippet:

```js
$scope.getUserInfo = function(user_id){
   $http.get('/api/?method=getuserprofile&userid='+user_id)
   .success(function(data) {
      $scope.userInfo = data.message;
   }).error(function(data) {
      console.log('getUserInfo->d!0cane');
   });
}
```

```html
<img class="bar-avatar" ng-show="userInfo.avatar_location" ng-src=" {{userInfo.avatar_location}}" alt="useravatar">
```

I tried to prevent AngularJS caching the file, but I couldn't manage to make it work! Any idea about the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try something like this to prevent caching, should work

```
.success(function(data) {
    $scope.userInfo = data.message;
    $scope.userInfo.avatar_location += '?' + Date.now();
});
```